# How set $_GET['code'] and $_SESSION['token'] while calling youtube commentthread api

Tags: php, api, session, youtube-api, comments

I have used complete code of youtube api for insert commentthread [youtube_v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert) but when I call API it gives me below error.

> Authorization Required
>
> You need to authorize access before proceeding.

When I clicked on "authorized access" it redirects to google error page and displays below content:

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> Application: Application Name
>
> You can email the developer of this application at: email address
>
> The redirect URI in the request, `http://localhost/done.php`, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit `https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/******-*******.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=*******` to update the authorized redirect URIs.

In this code,the `$_GET['code']` and `$_SESSION['token']` are not set so that  I cannot get access token so it gives me `redirect_uri_mismatch` error.

From where the value of `$_GET['code']` and `$_SESSION['token']` are set.
Code:

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why do you think that the error is related to that piece of code? The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: Yes @jeroen but from where the value of $_GET['code'] and $_SESSION['token'] are set?
I write the perfect code line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch), the redirect URI where the response is returned to has to be registered in the APIs console, and the [error](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#youtube.api.CommonRequestError) is indicating that you haven't done that, or haven't done it correctly.

> Go to the console for your project and look under API Access. You should see your client ID & secret there, along with a list of redirect URIs. If the URI you want isn't listed, click edit settings and add the URI to the list.

You can also check on these related SO questions:

- [Youtube API 3 Video Upload 400 Error: redirect_uri_mismatch OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993342/youtube-api-3-video-upload-400-error-redirect-uri-mismatch-oauth2)
- [400 Error: redirect_uri_mismatch for yotube video upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346233/400-error-redirect-uri-mismatch-for-yotube-video-upload)

Hope this helps!